how can I bring a selected text in a opened browser to excel sheet using Vba?
I have a task which I use it manually. I have to switch from Excel to a browser (e.g. chrome or Firefox or Microsoft edge) and copy a text (that is already selected) and paste it as HTML in Excel sheet. I should note that the the webpage is open and the text is always selected.
How can I do this task automatically with VBA?
Thank you so much
these are the steps: go to to browser - CTRL+C - Back to Excel - Paste as HTML
this code is working for just pasting the data.
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
 Dim CB As Object
 Set CB = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
 CB.GetFromClipboard
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
End Sub


Hi and welcome to S.O. please note that this is not a free code writing service. That said, if you start writing some VBA and get bogged down in a problem, we'd be happy to take a look at your code and help out. You've outlined the steps the macro needs to go through, which means you're ahead of a lot of people.

Try this out.  Note you can't step through this code using F8, since that puts the focus on the VB editor...
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range
    
    Set c = Selection
    AppActivate "Google Chrome" 'activate Chrome
    SendKeys "^c"  'copy any selected text in the active tab
    DoEvents
    AppActivate Application.Caption 'back to Excel...
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    c.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"
End Sub

You have to run this from Excel though, so there's likely not much benefit to this approach (you could just as easily Crl+C before switching to Excel and then paste)

The following example is to retrieve a data from HTML table that is hosted by a specific webpage. You can apply this example to any other HTML's elements. You can identify the HTML element that contains the data you looking for by right click the webpage and then select "View page source" option.
First step, you needs to add a reference to the following libraries to your VBA project:

Microsoft HTML Object Library ( C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb
)
Microsoft XML, v6.0 (C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll)


Sub RetrieveWebData()

Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim DataTable As HTMLTable: Dim DataRow As HTMLTableRow   

Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

xhr.Open "GET", "Your Webpage URL Here", False
xhr.send

If xhr.readyState = 4 And xhr.Status = 200 Then
   Set Doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
   Doc.body.innerHTML = xhr.responseText
Else
    MsgBox "Error" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & xhr.readyState & vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & xhr.Statuse                
End If

Set DataTable = Doc.getElementsByClassName("Class Name Here")(0)

If Not DataTable Is Nothing Then
   'loop through each row
   For Each DataRow In DataTable.Rows
       'you can use DataRow.Cells(index).innerText to get the value
       'more codes here
   Next
End If

Set xhr = Nothing
Set Doc = Nothing

End Sub

